# Extreme Learning Machine - why random weights rather than space-spanning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Putting aside the pros and cons of Extreme Learning Machines (ELMs), there is something pretty fundamental that I don't understand: why are the weights and biases in the hidden layer *randomised*?

Would it not be better to thoroughly span the weight-bias space with *ordered* values so that we can be sure that all of the space has been spanned? Surely randomised weights and biases might leave regions of the space sparsely populated and thus compromise the outcome, i.e. you don't have a node in a region where it would be beneficial to have one?

Compare the two figures at the top-right of the [Sobol sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence) Wikipedia page, for instance. The pseudorandom sequence produces a lot of empty regions in comparison with the sobol sequence.

*Pseudorandom Sequence*
[image: Pseudorandom Sequence]

*Sobol Sequence*
[image]
<sub>Images by Jheald [CC BY-SA 3.0  (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)], from Wikimedia Commons</sub>

Comment: The reason is simply the feature space. It is very big. You can't believe it :)

Comment: @Media I'm not sure that's correct, as the space I'm talking about here is the 2D weight-bias space for the hidden layer, which is set as per the first diagram in a conventional Extreme Learning Machine, as I understand it.

Comment: @Media ...or was that a Hitchhiker's Guide joke?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Actually, I didn't find time to read the paper. What I've said is a general fact about neural networks.